# I2C communication between 2 Arduinos with updated wire library

Tags: i2c, wire-library

I would like to enable communication between two Arduino 101. From what I have read, the best method is to use I2C using the wire library. However, it seems as though the newest Arduino IDE has an updated version of the Wire library that no longer includes the `begin(int)` and `onRequest` functions.

All of the tutorials for I2C communication use these methods, so I am unable to follow and use them. It looks like when I change the board to Arduino Uno these functions are found, but as soon as I change the board to Arduino 101 the following errors appear no matching function for call to `TwoWire::begin(int)`.

When I try replacing my wire library with the older version, I get other errors for missing libraries and if I replace everything it is unable to compile on Arduino 101.

Can someone please help me or direct me to a I2C tutorial that uses the most updated version of the Wire library?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is the Arduino 101 uses an Intel microprocessor (Curie) instead of an Atmel microprocessor.

The only information I could find is on the [Arduino page for the 101](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoard101), which mentions it has dedicated pins for I2C, but it also says that you can use the Wire library. Maybe you just need to update your IDE?

I'd help more, but I can't seem to find any useful information on the Curie...

Answer (score 0):

Although I did not manage to get wire communication to work, I was able to get the Arduinos to communicate through serial port. You just need to ensure to use Serial1 rather than Serial.